# What is the proper way to query the couchdb's _users database from node?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, cradle

I am using the cradle package on node to query couchdb. My node instance
has admin privileges.

I am looking for the proper way to query the _users table from node.

right now, I am doing something like this:

```
  var db = conn.database('_users');
  db.exists(function (err, exists) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error', err);
    } else if (exists) {
       db.get('org.couchdb.user:some_user', function (err, doc) {
          console.log(doc);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('database does not exists.');
    }
  });
```

Is there a cleaner way to doing this? any auth libraries similar to pouchdb-authentication?

**THIS IS WHAT I DID**
At the time, I wasn't aware that I could just as easily use pouchdb on node. I will be using it plus pouchdb-authentication to simplify requests to to _users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use PouchDB on top of the `_users` database:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/_users');
db.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then(/* ... */) // <-- fetches all users
```

`_users` is just a database. :)

Comment: Hey nolan I am using node as a server to interact with my pouchdb client (which runs in the browser as a chrome extension). I just googled and I noticed there is a pouchdb server running on express. I now think that perhaps I should stop using express + cradle and use something like express-pouchdb instead. what do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify: I am new to node + couch/pouchdb so I am trying to avoid making silly decisions. My chrome extension in the browser is running pouch. on occasion, it fires an async request to the node server to perform some "secure admin operation" that the client shouldn't be able to do. The node server does not need to sync but it needs to interface with couchdb. I am currently using cradle which works well but lacks the ability to interact with _users database nicely.

Comment: Yup, feel free to use express-pouchdb, pouchdb-server, or CouchDB. The former two are already nearly feature-compliant with CouchDB, although last I tested, CouchDB is about 2x faster. Whichever one you find easier to use. :)

Comment: cool cool. I think I will use pouchdb + pouchdb authentication on node just to standardize the way I use couchdb on both the client and server. thanks man!

Comment: what's the cleanest add a role to a user through pouchdb-authentication?

Comment: Roles are added to user docs, so just modify the doc. :) set the roles, then do `db.put()` like you normally would.